# Raw pointer inside std::make_shared

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, raii

I readily admit to still learning the finer notes of pointers in C/C++ and how they work but after doing some research, I just don't *feel* comfortable with the code below.

```
std::shared_ptr<CDKSCREEN> cdkScreen;
cdkScreen = std::make_shared<CDKSCREEN>(*initCDKScreen(newWin.get()));
```

Does the usage of raw pointers inside a `std::shared_ptr` nullify any of the benefits you get from using smart pointers? Or is it just all the same either way? Thank you and I appreciate any answers to this post.

---

EDIT:
I did not realize the full purpose of the `reset()` function but thank you to all who pointed this out to me. It seems I can also pass a custom destructor to `std::shared_ptr` as well, like below:

```
std::shared_ptr<CDKSCREEN> cdkScreen(initCDKScreen(newWin.get()), destroyCDKScreen);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, `make_shared` constructs the dynamically-allocated object internally. You can only supply a raw pointer when directly constructing a `shared_ptr` object.

Comment: @JAB it's invoking a copy-ctor in this case

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz That would mean that CDKSCREEN is itself a pointer to some type and thus make the usage of shared_ptr irrelevant as the object being pointed to won't get the benefits of using it.

Comment: @JAB um, why? it's passed as a nonpointer type param to `shared_ptr` (correctly) and then `init...` is dereferences to produce a value, which is then consumed by the copy-ctor ran by `make_shared`. If anything, it has a memory leak.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Oh, you're correct. I misinterpreted what `initCDKScreen` was supposed to be doing and assumed OP was talking about supplying a raw pointer directly to `make_shared`, which gave me the impression that the dereference was to another pointer type.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I know at least one framework (Qt) that has a macro for and recommends deleting/hiding copy constructors for classes designed to be primarily dynamically allocated in order to avoid such memory leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your example actually has a memory leak. Let's break it down:

```
CDKSCREEN* screen = initCDKScreen(newWin.get());
CDKSCREEN& screenRef = *screen;

// auto screenSharedPtr = std::make_shared<CDKSCREEN>(screenRef);
// this is basically:

CDKSCREEN* screen2 = new CDKSCREEN(screenRef);
shared_ptr<CDKSCREEN> screenSharedPtr (screen2);
```

As you can see, a copy is being made, but the original pointer isn't deleted. Oops.

---

If `initCDKScreen` returns something that has to just be `delete`d, then in this case I'd avoid the copy/move ctor and just `.reset()` the smart pointer to it:

```
std::shared_ptr<CDKSCREEN> cdkScreen;
cdkScreen.reset(initCDKScreen(newWin.get()));
```

Actually, since it even has a constructor overload for that, go ahead and

```
std::shared_ptr<CDKSCREEN> cdkScreen { initCDKScreen(newWin.get()) };
```

If a custom destruction facility is needed, you can pass it as a 2nd parameter to the pointer. It makes perfect sense and smart pointer classes were designed for that.

Comment: Ooops, I guess that was quite the blatant mistake :) Thank you for such an awesome response, I also didn't realize you could pass a custom destructor as a second parameter either, as explained further by JojOatXGME below. I didn't see that in any of the examples I looked at.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to save the pointer returned by initCDKScreen. In this case you don't have to use `make_shared`. You should pass the pointer to the constructor or `shared_ptr::reset(...)`:

```
std::shared_ptr<CDKSCREEN> cdkScreen(initCDKScreen(newWin.get()));
```

Since `CDKSCREEN` should be destroyed by `destroyCDKScreen(CDKSCREEN *screen)` and not with `delete`, you should write something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<CDKSCREEN> cdkScreen(initCDKScreen(newWin.get()), destroyCDKScreen);
```

or

```
std::shared_ptr<CDKSCREEN> cdkScreen;
cdkScreen.reset(initCDKScreen(newWin.get()), destroyCDKScreen);
```

Comment: Yes, I would like to save the pointer returned and use it throughout the application as the primary source of creating screens. Sorry I did not explain this so well. I also did not realize you could pass a custom destructor to it either, as that was not shown in any of the examples I looked at. I did not understand the full purpose of reset as well and until now. Thank you for the wonderful response :)

Answer (score 2):

> Does the usage of raw pointers inside a std::shared_ptr nullify any of the benefits you get from using smart pointers? Or is it just all the same either way? Thank you and I appreciate any answers to this post.

No, that's the entire purpose of the smart pointer. You no longer are responsible for maintenance of the raw pointer. The smart pointer object is. The smart pointer object takes ownership of the raw pointer. When the smart pointer expires (goes out of scope, or is deleted), it will automatically delete the pointer it owns. The important bit here is the scope: this way you don't have to remember to delete it yourself if you `return` or `throw` somewhere.

`unique_ptr` attempts to describe the concept that there's only ever one current thread of execution which is using the object. `shared_ptr` expands on that by stating that there *may* be multiple threads attempting to access it simultaneously. *But remember: `shared_ptr` does NOT guarantee concurrency or safety for the object it points to. It only guarantees concurrency and safety of the pointer itself.*